# Error TS2322 on TypeScript Type 'IGames[]' is not assignable

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I want to fetch my data from Localhost on angular using Http and Observable this are my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IGames } from './games';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GamesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  test():Observable<any>{
    return of("test");
  }
  getGames():Observable<IGames[]>{
    return this.http.get<IGames[]>('http://localhost/pmn/uas/getgames.php');
  }
}
```

I create this constructor so i can get it from everywhere

```
export interface IGames{id:number, name:string, description:string, pictute:string}
```

this is my games.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GamesService } from '../games.service';
import { IGames } from '../games';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-games',
  templateUrl: './games.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./games.component.css']
})
export class GamesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private gs:GamesService) { }
  games=[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.gs.getGames().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.games=data;
        console.log=data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

this code work though but on my terminal it always shows this error

```
ERROR in src/app/games/games.component.ts(18,9): error TS2322: Type 'IGames[]' is not assignable to type '(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => void'.
  Type 'IGames[]' provides no match for the signature '(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void'.
```

Comment: works for me just fine, with 2 changes: 1) move `GamesComponent.games` declaration above constructor, and add type: `games: IGames[] = [];` 2) `console.log=data` should be `console.log(data);`

Comment: It work perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me just fine, with 2 changes: 1) move `GamesComponent.games` declaration above constructor, and add type: `games: IGames[] = [];` 2) console.log=data should be `console.log(data);`

```
export class GamesComponent implements OnInit {

  // members should be above constructor
  games: IGames = [];

  constructor(private gs:GamesService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.gs.getGames().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.games=data;
        // console.log is a function
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i got another error same like this but i've copy paste it from this answer and it's still error it says **Property 'includes' is missing in type 'IGames'.**

Comment: For me works just fine, may be you edited something else also. Some times `ng serve` needs to be restarted also.